# Rich edit control: difference between rcPage and rc members of FORMATRANGE structure

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, richtextbox

The Win32 [rich edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a message called [`EM_FORMATRANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788020%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that can render the contents of the control to an arbitrary device context.  This is often used for printing or print preview, but could be used with any device context.  This message accepts a structure called [`FORMATRANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct _formatrange {
  HDC       hdc;
  HDC       hdcTarget;
  RECT      rc;
  RECT      rcPage;
  CHARRANGE chrg;
} FORMATRANGE;
```

The only documentation for `rc` and `rcPage` is the following:

> **`rc`**: The area to render to. Units are measured in twips.
>
> **`rcPage`**: The entire area of a page on the rendering device. Units are measured in twips.
>
> The values for `rc` and `rcPage` can be obtained by using [`GetDeviceCaps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It is not completely clear to me what the difference between rcPage and rc is.  The code examples I have seen online seem to set both of these to the same rectangle.  Microsoft's own example [How to Print the Contents of Rich Edit Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) completely fails to initialize `rcPage` and actually passes undefined data to the rich edit control.

Is `rcPage` even used by the rich edit control?  I can't see why a second rectangle might be useful for affecting the behavior of this command, so what is it there for?  Can someone provide an example illustrating the difference between `rc` and `rcPage`?

Comment: I'm guessing it's like window rect vs. client rect.

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to does actually set the rcPage part to the maximum dimensions of the printer, e.g. exactly what the documentation is saying, whereas the rc is set to the actual printable sections of the page which aren't the same, normally printers have a border around the page where it can't physically print. The reason there's two is probably for when something is absolutely positioned on the page but you're only partially rendering a part of it so it needs that information to properly offset elements.